# How to fix spark unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

when I read data from HDFS using sparkSql interface, some tasks throw  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I think that there may be some bad record in the dataset which make the task failed. How can I get the bad record ? Or how can I ignore the bad record when I load data using spark interface to make the application successful?

the full error log in the failed task is posted below(It seems like some utf8 decode error):

```
17/06/17 23:02:19 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 42.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 42)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 62
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numBytesForFirstByte(UTF8String.java:156)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.numChars(UTF8String.java:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I lookup the utf8 encoding and spark source code (posted below). According to the utf8 encoding, the length of one char in utf8 must be between 1 and 6. So the max available code point is 11111101b. So the 'offset' variable in the spark source code must be no more than 11111101b - 192 = 61. There should be some bad record in the data which is illegal for the utf8 encoding.

So how can I select them out? Or how can I skip the bad record?

```
private static int[] bytesOfCodePointInUTF8 = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
    5, 5, 5, 5,
    6, 6};


  private static int numBytesForFirstByte(final byte b) {
    final int offset = (b & 0xFF) - 192;
    return (offset >= 0) ? bytesOfCodePointInUTF8[offset] : 1;
  }
```

Comment: What's the Dataset? What aggregation do you do?

Answer (score 0):

You seem (guessing by `agg_doAggregateWithKeys`) working with typed Dataset API.

I'd recommend using `Dataset.rdd` to access the underlying `RDD[InternalRow]` and work with UnsafeRows directly to see what string might be causing the issue.

Don't touch any of the methods that could convert the dataset using encoders (so you avoid conversions with `UTF8String`).

Answer (score 0):

try below ,`option mutiline =true` solve this issue

```
  val data = spark.read.option("header","false").
      option("delimiter", "|").
      **option("multiline", "true").**
          csv("test.unl")
```